# Passing data from child to parent after Array State has been updated, Why am I getting an instance of the prev state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

This function is added to a button click.

```
  const listChangeHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIngredientList((prevArray) => [...prevArray, ingredient]);
    inputIngredient.current.value = "";

    props.data(ingredientList);
  };
```

**Problem is:** The received state (ingredientList) that I get in the *parent comp* is the previous, not the latest thats shown in the *child component*

Why and what could be the workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to this fact that `state` always updates after rerendering, so when you pass it to upper component, it still has its previous value!
To solve this problem you have two solutions:

1. update your code as follow:

```
const listChangeHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let temp = [...ingredientList, ingredient];
    setIngredientList(temp);
    inputIngredient.current.value = "";

    props.data(temp);
  };
```

2. use `useRef` instead of `useState` because in contrast to `state`, `ref` updates imediately.

Comment: happy to help. @LajosBela